# How to store the Json in a Django Db as text

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am sending a POST request from my front-end from which I want to save the JSON into my database as a text field
I am using django rest framework and sqlite db.

My serializer class is

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    json_data = serializers.JSONField()

    def create(self,validated_data):
        return TableUser.objects.create(json_data=validated_data)
```

and my model is

```
class TableUser(models.Model):
    username = models.TextField(default="unlogged")
    json_data = models.TextField()
```

When i send the POST request it stores

```
1|unlogged|{'json_data': {'json_data': ['Value must be valid JSON.']}}
```

in my db instead of the actual JSON I am sending.

So, How do I just simply store the whole JSON in my textfield in whatever format it comes.

Comment: The code looks correct. Can you share your html and the text you are adding to the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
import json


def create_table_user(self, json_data: dict):
        return TableUser.objects.create(json_data=json.dumps(json_data))
```

your example of stored data is more likely a validation error